# Define value in btn-group using twitter-bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem when using bootstrap in my code.  I want the value from my btn-radio, but I cannot find out how to do it.

```
<label>Status</label>
<div class="btn-group" id="filterProductStatus" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
<button class="btn active">All</button>
<button class="btn">Online</button>
<button class="btn">Offline</button>
</div>
```

I want to get the value of the preset button and later the selected button; can someonne help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I completed this question myself by using `(  $('#filterProductStatus.active').val() )`. This has help me to do what I needed to do.

Comment: Please mark Josh's answer as the accepted one as, for the code provided, this script will not give the desired result.

Answer (score 16):

The accepted answer won't work as you need to select a child button, not the part div.  I think you'll find this works:

```
$('#filterProductStatus > button.active').text()
```

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be marked as accepted.  Here is the working code: http://jsfiddle.net/Bt6Qx/