# get the value from a twitter-bootstrap radio data-toggle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

I am trying to get the value from a twitter-bootstrap data-toggle="buttons-radio" submitted, along with comments from a comments field, in a form_for in rails using erb. I have seen these posts, but I can't quite connect the dots, probably because I don't know any javascript.

[Twitter bootstrap radio buttons not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462434/twitter-bootstrap-radio-buttons-not-working)

[Define value in btn-group using twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570368/define-value-in-btn-group-using-twitter-bootstrap)

[With Twitter Bootstrap toggle radio buttons, what's the clean way to get form input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11475069/with-twitter-bootstrap-toggle-radio-buttons-whats-the-clean-way-to-get-form-in)

```
<%= form_for @approval, :url => approve_path, :method => :put, :html => { :id => "other_version_form" }  do |f| %>
  <fieldset>
      <p>
      <b>Comments:</b><br>
      <%= f.text_area :comments, :size => "200x3" %>
    </p>

    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" name="approval[version]" id="approval_version" value="<%= "#{@latest}" %>"><%= "#{@latest}" %></button>
      <% @versions.each do |v| %>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" name="approval[version]" id="approval_version" value="<%= "#{v}" %>"><%= "#{v}" %></button>
      <% end %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
      <%= link_to 'Cancel', approvals_path, :class => 'btn' %>
    </div>

  </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

The form ends up looking like this:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/approvals/approve/1394" class="edit_approval" id="other_version_form" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="Q0848ftQQk8S2pWiSpkcozcRalk3qw8yZolZKQBx74s=" /></div>
  <fieldset>
    <p>
      <b>Comments:</b><br>
      <textarea cols="200" id="approval_comments" name="approval[comments]" rows="3"></textarea>
    </p>

    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" name="approval[version]" id="approval_version" value="3.29.13">3.29.13</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" name="approval[version]" id="approval_version" value="3.29.12">3.29.12</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" name="approval[version]" id="approval_version" value="3.29.11">3.29.11</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" name="approval[version]" id="approval_version" value="3.29.10">3.29.10</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" name="approval[version]" id="approval_version" value="3.29.9">3.29.9</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
      <input class="btn btn-primary" name="commit" type="submit" value="Update Approval" />
      <a href="/approvals" class="btn">Cancel</a>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

But when I submit the form and inspect the params from the controller, I only get the comments and I need the selected value to get passed in, too:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"put", "authenticity_token"=>"Q0848ftQQk8S2pWiSpkcozcRalk3qw8yZolZKQBx74s=", "approval"=>{"comments"=>"here is the deal"}, "commit"=>"Update Approval", "controller"=>"approvals", "action"=>"approve", "id"=>"1394"}
```

Thanks.

```
===Tried http://dan.doezema.com/2012/03/twitter-bootstrap-radio-button-form-inputs/ ===
===ALL GOOD====
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    $('div.btn-group[data-toggle-name=*]').each(function(){
        var group   = $(this);
        var form    = group.parents('form').eq(0);
        var name    = group.attr('data-toggle-name');
        var hidden  = $('input[name="' + name + '"]', form);
        $('button', group).each(function(){
            var button = $(this);
            button.live('click', function(){
                hidden.val($(this).val());
            });
            if(button.val() == hidden.val()) {
                button.addClass('active');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle-name="version" data-toggle="buttons-radio" >
      <button type="button" value="<%= "#{@latest}" %>" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="button"><%= "#{@latest}" %></button>
      <% @versions.each do |v| %>
          <button type="button" value="<%= "#{v}" %>" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="button"><%= "#{v}" %></button>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="version" value="0" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `<input type="radio"...` instead of `<button type="button"...`

Comment: That did get the data I needed into my controller, but it took away the lovely twitter-bootstrap button bar and simply replaced it with a radio button group. I can live with that, but would like to keep the formatting.

Comment: Google finds this. It may help. http://dan.doezema.com/2012/03/twitter-bootstrap-radio-button-form-inputs/

Comment: I had seen that, but in revisiting it, it works! Thanks for your help, @saverio

Comment: A more graceful way of doing it (I think :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/16214643/1111662

Answer (score 1):

My answer is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/16214643/1111662

In your **view** (I use HAML but convert to ERB if needed)

```
.btn-group{data:{toggle: "buttons-radio"}}
  %label.btn
    = f.radio_button :gender, "Male"
    Male
  %label.btn
    = f.radio_button :gender, "Female"
    Female
```

In your **view-specific javascript** e.g. `pages.js.coffee` (again, I use CoffeeScript but convert to plain JS JQuery if needed)

```
$ ->
  $('.btn-group label.btn input[type=radio]')
    .hide()
    .filter(':checked').parent('.btn').addClass('active')
```

The JS is for making a button look "selected" when the view loads. It first hides the radiobuttons and then through chained JQuery syntax adds Twitter Bootstrap class 'active' to the now hidden yet still selected radiobutton. Pseudo-class `:checked` allows finding the right radiobutton.

And for a single checkbutton

**view (HAML)**

```
.btn{data:{toggle: "buttons-radio"}}
  = f.check_box :public
  Public
```

**JS (CoffeeScript)**

```
activateRadioButton = ($element) ->
  hiddenField = $element.children('input[type=hidden]')
  toggleInputValue hiddenField

toggleInputValue = ($input) ->
  switch $input.val()
    when "0" then $input.val('1')
    when "1" then $input.val('0') 

$ ->
  $('.btn input[type=checkbox]')
    .hide()
    .filter(':checked').parent('.btn').addClass('active')
```

Rails uses a hidden field for the checkbutton (see [RubyOnRails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box)) thus we need to add an onclick handler to change the hidden field

**NB** Use f.submit rather than submit_tag for this to work